# How to pick value from list if gap(diff) is larger than a define number

Tags: python

`a = [44, 52, 59, 62, 174, 175, 178, 288, 292, 404, 408, 518, 521, 633, 637, 747, 751, 863, 867, 977, 980, 987]`

For example, on above list, if the gap is 100, then first 3 items should be filter out.

final result should be:

`b = [62, 174, 288, 404, 518, 633, 747, 863, 977]`

here is my code:

```
def pick(lst, gap):
    result = []
    first_item_picked = False
    for idx, x in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            if not first_item_picked and idx < len(lst)-1 and lst[idx+1]-x > gap:
                first_item_picked = True
                result.append(x)
            elif x- lst[idx-1] > gap:
                result.append(x)
        except:
            print(idx,x)
    return result

b = pick(a,100)
print(b)
```

How to write a more simple algorithm to make it?

Comment: First, write down and understand the "rules" of the algorithm, step by step, then try to write Python code for it. If you have a specific issue while doing this, you can ask here with your code.

Comment: my code added. Just found if there is easier way.

Comment: explain what you mean by gap and what criteria needs to checked when filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.pairwise` to iterate through the input list in pairs, and if the gap between a pair is greater than the threshold, append the latter of the pair to the output, but also append the former to the output if it is going to be the first output item:

```
from itertools import pairwise

def pick(lst, gap):
    output = []
    for a, b in pairwise(lst):
        if b - a > gap:
            if not output:
                output.append(a)
            output.append(b)
    return output
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/KnobbyUsefulAbility

Comment: This is just what I need! pairwise !

Answer (score -1):

```py
>>> a = [44, 52, 59, 62, 174, 175, 178, 288, 292, 404, 408, 518, 521, 633, 637, 747, 751, 863, 867, 977, 980, 987]
>>> res = []
>>> for (v, nxt) in zip(a, a[1:]):
...  if res:
...   if res[-1] + 100 <= v:
...    res.append(v)
...  else:
...   if v + 100 <= nxt:
...    res.append(v)
...
>>> res
[62, 174, 288, 404, 518, 633, 747, 863, 977]
```